# Вопрос об оформлении блока на css. Нижний блок должен быть меньше верхнего и зависеть от высоты верхнего

Tags: html, css

Не получается решить такую задачу. Нижний блок должен быть меньше верхнего и зависеть от высоты верхнего. Белая обводка должна проглядывать сквозь градиентную заливку. Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением.

Вот, как было задумано.

[image: Вот, как было задумано.]

```css
body{
  background:green;
}
.who-needs {
  
  background:green;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 7px 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  text-align: center;
}

.who-needs h2 {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.who-needs-block-border {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 380px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 12, 48, .3), rgba(0, 12, 48, .8));
  margin: 30px 25px;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
}

.who-needs-block {
  position: relative;
  top: -17px;
  left: -19px;
  width: 330px;
  padding: 20px 40px 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 12, 48, .3), rgba(0, 12, 48, .8));
}
```

```html
<div id="who-needs" class="who-needs">

      <div class="who-needs-block-border">
        <div class="who-needs-block">
          <h2>текст</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: что значит "зависеть от высоты"? что значит "проглядывать сквозь градиентную заливку"? прикрепите картинку - как должно в итоге быть

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/nvS6x0/image.jpg - вот так должно получиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот моё решение:
 - вынести текст и .who-needs-block на один уровень;
 - изменить чуть стили;

```css
    body{
      background:green;
    }
    .who-needs {

      background:green;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 7px 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
      text-align: center;
    }

    .who-needs h2 {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 500;
    }

    .who-needs-block-border {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      width: 380px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 12, 48, .3), rgba(0, 12, 48, .8));
      margin: 30px 25px;
      border: 6px solid #fff;
    }

    .who-needs-block {
      position: absolute;
      top: -20px;
      left: -20px;
      width: 340px;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 20px 40px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 12, 48, .3), rgba(0, 12, 48, .8));
    }
```

```html
<div id="who-needs" class="who-needs">
  <div class="who-needs-block-border">
    <div class="who-needs-block"></div>
    <h2>текст</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за решение! Очень помогло. Огромное спасибо! Очень-очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
background:green;
}
.who-needs {

  background:green;
  color: #fff;
text-shadow: 7px 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 
0, .75);
text-align: center;
}

.who-needs h2 {
   text-align: justify;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 500;
   margin: 0px;
   }


 .who-needs-block-border {
   position: relative;
 float: left;
    width: 380px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 12, 48, .3), rgba(0, 12, 48, .8));
   margin: 30px 25px;
}
  .who-needs-block {
margin: 15px;
  border: 6px solid #fff;
  border-radius:20px;
  padding:15px;
}
```

.

```
  <div class="who-needs-block-border">
    <div class="who-needs-block">
      <h2>текст</h2>
      loreloremm lorem lorem loreloremm lorem lorem loreloremm lorem lorem loreloremm lorem lorem 
      loreloremm lorem lorem loreloremm lorem lorem
    </div>
  </div>
```

Вот, как вы хотели.

Comment: Благодарю за труд и решение. Но это не совсем то, тут белая обводка сверху, а мне нужно, чтобы просвечивала из под верхнего блока. Решение подсказали чуть выше. Но все-равно очень благодарна за то, что хотите помочь. Благодарю)